# Creating a lift chart for a classification tree

Tags: regression, classifying-spaces, data-mining

This is likely a simple question but I'm new to data mining techniques and am trying to compare two different predictive models.  I've created a logistic regression and a classification tree and would like to look at the lift charts for both to compare their performance.

I understand how to construct the lift chart with a regression, I order the predictions of the validation set in descending order and compare it with the cumulative sums of the observed points.

However, for something like a classification tree where the output is a 1 or 0, how do I order the validation data points for the lift chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out most models do produce a confidence or a score as well as a classification.  I had trouble finding this in MATLAB but it does produce confidence values.  This value is continuous and can be re-ordered to produce a lift chart